# Are real numbers just a vector space over R?

Tags: vector-spaces, real-numbers

If so, how would you explain...

Vector-spaces definition doesn't specify the need for a multiplicative inverse
(only multiply by scalars).

...but on the other hand:

A property of real numbers is that there exists a multiplicative inverse.

Properties of vector-spaces:
http://www.math.niu.edu/~beachy/courses/240/vectorspace.pdf
Properties of real numbers:
https://www.cengage.com/resource_uploads/downloads/1133963021_375161.pdf?source=post_page---------------------------   (p2)

Comment: What's the multiplicative inverse of $0$?

Comment: The multiplicative inverse of 0, 1/0 is undefined, hence why it is a condition listed beside multiplicative inverse listed in the link: https://www.cengage.com/resource_uploads/downloads/1133963021_375161.pdf?source=post_page---------------------------

Comment: Real numbers *are* a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, but no, real numbers are not *just* a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. A dog is an animal, but a dog is not *just* an animal. Socrates was a Greek man, but he was not *just* a Greek man. Etc.

Comment: I feel like this question is seriously missing some context - why *would* someone think that the reals are "just" a vector space? - but it's worth noting that there is a very interesting (informal) question in the background here: when is one kind of structure on the reals (or anything, really) "derivable" from another? This leads in a few different directions, in particular to [model theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real numbers are a vector space, but they have additional properties too (such as multiplicative inverses, as you mentioned).

Similarly, a cat is an animal with whiskers (an additional property). Just because something is an animal, it doesn't mean it needs to have whiskers!